# MySQL: Strange behavior of UPDATE query (ERROR 1062 Duplicate entry)

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mysql-error-1062

I have a MySQL database the stores news articles with the publications date (just day information), the source, and category. Based on these I want to generate a table that holds the article counts w.r.t. to these 3 parameters.

Since for some combinations of these 3 parameters there might be no article, a simple GROUP BY won't do. I therefore first generate a table `news_article_counts` with all possible combinations of the 3 parameters, and an default `article_count` of 0 -- like this:

```
SELECT * FROM news_article_counts;
+--------------+------------+----------+---------------+
| published_at | source     | category | article_count |
+------------- +------------+----------+---------------+
| 2016-08-05   | 1826089206 |        0 |             0 |
| 2016-08-05   | 1826089206 |        1 |             0 |
| 2016-08-05   | 1826089206 |        2 |             0 |
| 2016-08-05   | 1826089206 |        3 |             0 |
| 2016-08-05   | 1826089206 |        4 |             0 |
| ...          | ...        |      ... |           ... |
+--------------+------------+----------+---------------+
```

For testing, I now created a temporary table `tmp` as the GROUP BY result from the original news article table:

```
SELECT * FROM tmp LIMIT 6;
+--------------+------------+----------+-----+
| published_at | source     | category | cnt |
+--------------+------------+----------+-----+
| 2016-08-05   | 1826089206 |        3 |   1 |
| 2003-09-19   | 1826089206 |        4 |   1 |
| 2005-08-08   | 1826089206 |        3 |   1 |
| 2008-07-22   | 1826089206 |        4 |   1 |
| 2008-11-26   | 1826089206 |        8 |   1 |
| ...          | ...        |      ... | ... |
+--------------+------------+----------+-----+
```

Given these two tables, the following query works as expected:

```
SELECT * FROM news_article_counts c, tmp t
WHERE c.published_at = t.published_at AND c.source = t.source AND c.category = t.category;
```

But now I need to update the `article_count` of table `news_article_counts` with the values in table `tmp` where the 3 parameters match up. For this I'm using the following query (I've tried different ways but with the same results):

```
UPDATE 
  news_article_counts c
INNER JOIN
  tmp t
ON
  c.published_at = t.published_at AND
  c.source = t.source AND
  c.category = t.category
SET
  c.article_count = t.cnt;
```

Executing this query yields this error:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2018-04-07 14:46:17-1826089206-1' for key 'uniqueIndex'
```

`uniqueIndex` is a joint index over `published_at`, `source`, `category` of table `news_article_counts`. But this shouldn't be a problem since I do not -- as far as I can tell -- update any of those 3 values, only `article_count`.

What confuses me most is that in the error it mentions the timestamp I executed the query (here: `2018-04-07 14:46:17`). I have no absolutely idea where this comes into play. In fact, some rows in `news_article_counts` now have `2018-04-07 14:46:17` as value for `published_at`. While this explains the error, I cannot see why `published_at` gets overwritten with the current timestamp. There is no `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on this column; see:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`news_article_counts` (
  `published_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `source` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `category` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `article_count` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  UNIQUE INDEX `uniqueIndex` (`published_at` ASC, `source` ASC, `category`  ASC))
ENGINE = MyISAM
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4;
```

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE 1**: I actually checked the table definition of `news_article_counts` in the database. And there's indeed the following:

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM news_article_counts;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| published_at  | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| source        | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| category      | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| article_count | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                 |                             |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

But why is `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` set. I double and triple-checked my CREATE TABLE statement. I removed the joint index, I added an artificial primary key (auto_increment). Nothing help. I've even tried to explicitly remove these attributes from `published_at` with:

```
ALTER TABLE `news_article_counts` CHANGE `published_at` `published_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

Nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara But he's not using that option.

Comment: This does seem weird. Can you reproduce it at sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct table definition? Your output above just shows a date, but a `TIMESTAMP` would display as a date and time.

Comment: @Christian are you sure that table schema is same as first time you CREATE TABLE? Can you make sure that no ALTER TABLE executed that change your table schema?

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara There's definitely no `ALTER TABLE` anywhere; and no `ON UPDATE` statement. @Barmer: I removed the `00:00:00` from `2016-08-05 00:00:00` to reduce the text a bit.

Comment: Are you sure that a group by won't work? Using left/right joins might make that possible, and allow you to avoid creating and maintaining this table. Can you show the schema of the table(s) that are the source for the new table?

Comment: @Christian I never got your comment for 2 reasons: 1) You can only put one @ in a comment, and 2) you misspelled my name, even though SO provides automatic name completion after @.

Comment: @Barmar noted with thanks and sorry for the typo! I've updated my questions since I could drill down the problem at least to some extent.

Comment: Take a look at the [explicit_defaults_for_timestamp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp) system variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the [`explicit_defaults_for_timestamp`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp) system variable disabled. One of the effects of this is:

> The first `TIMESTAMP` column in a table, if not explicitly declared with the `NULL` attribute or an explicit `DEFAULT` or `ON UPDATE` attribute, is automatically declared with the `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` attributes.

You could try enabling this system variable, but that could potentially impact other applications. I think it only takes effect when you're actually creating a table, so it shouldn't affect any existing tables.

If you don't to make a system-level change like this, you could add an explicit `DEFAULT` attribute to the `published_at` column of this table, then it won't automatically add `ON UPDATE`.

Comment: spot on! I've just tested it and solved everything. Very much appreciated!